# Странное поведение программы при динамическом выделении памяти

Tags: c++, строки, память, char

Столкнулся с довольно странным, как мне кажется, поведением оператора `new`.
Программа, представленная ниже, получает на вход строку, которая, по сути, нужна только для того, чтобы узнать количество введенных символов, - алгоритм упрощен для демонстрации проблемы, и на самом деле все переменные используются сполна, - а после выделить память под массив из `name.length()` символов.

Суть проблемы: при вводе строки, соблюдая условие: `name.length() % 8 == 0`, появляются лишние символы - дополнительный мусор - на выходе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    char * key;

    getline(std::cin, name);

    key = new char[name.length()];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        key[i] = 'A';
    }

    std::cout << key << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

1. Входные данные: **qwertyui**; на выходе: **AAAAAAAAха>**
2. Входные данные: **qwertyu**; на выходе: **AAAAAAA**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли о том, что в C-строке должен быть завершающий нулевой символ. Поэтому при выводе на экран выводятся ваши символы и содержимое памяти после них, пока не встретится нулик...

Comment: Почему проблема проявляется только в случае, если строка состоит из восьми символов? Совпадение? Предполагаю, конечно, что это как-то связано с устройством хранения данных и их особенностями, но уверенности в этом нет

Comment: @Marionette Вполне возможно, что конкретно у вашей программы при ее старте, в той точке, где выделяется память в начале лежат 8 нулей. А дальше идут не нули.

Comment: @Marionette, конечно, конкретные особенности (указали бы CPU, ОС и версии библиотек). Скорее всего, выделяемая память в начале обнулена (это когда ее пул запросили у ОС), запрашиваемый в new кусочек округляется до 8, далее идет служебная информация в свободном блоке. Очевидно, что все подробности в сорсах соответствующих либ

Comment: Ну вам же сказали: "...пока не встретится нулик".  В одном случаи этот нулик встречается после двух символов, в другом_вам везет еще больше, и встречается сразу

Comment: @avp, можете, в таком случае, можете ответить на несколько вопросов, которые, говоря откровенно, слабо относятся к теме этого вопроса? Вернее, поправьте меня, если я в чем-то заблуждаюсь. При запуске программе выделяются две, хм, структуры памяти - стек и куча. В стеке хранится информация о передаваемых значениях функций, адреса и, может, еще чего. В куче же некоторые ресурсы программы и другие данные: строки, переменные. Пул - это куча? Когда ОС отдает кучу - она заполнена нулями? Если так, то откуда мусор в выводе? И почему тогда при создании переменной она содержит данные из памяти?

Comment: @avp, еще немного. Оператор `new` запрашивает дополнительную память у ОС? В куче ведь много, - при запуске, - свободного места? Округляется? То есть вместо, скажем, 7 байт выделяется 8?

Comment: @Marionette, да можете считать, что пул это куча (один из пулов в куче, остальные аллокатор памяти запрашивает отдельно). А вообще очень много вопросов для ответа в комментариях. Задавайте их по отдельности как вопросы на главной странице (или в каком-нибудь чате)

Comment: @avp, хорошо, создам отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Исправленный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string name;
    char * key;

    getline(std::cin, name);

    key = new char[name.length() + 1];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        key[i] = 'A';
    }
    key[name.length()] = '\0';

    std::cout << key << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```