# Фундаментальные вопросы по работе C++ с памятью

Tags: c++, память

*У меня есть некоторые трудности в понимании работы C++ с памятью. Надеюсь их разрешить.*

> Представим, существует некоторая программа, написанная на языке C++, и ее
>   только запустили на компьютере (x86_64).

---

Насколько мне известно, при запуске программе выделяются две структуры памяти - стек и куча. В стеке хранится информация о передаваемых значениях функций, адреса и, может, еще чего. В куче же некоторые ресурсы программы и другие данные: пользовательские строки, переменные - в общем, данные, появившиеся во время работы программы.

1. Термин "пул" - что он означает? Он как-то связан с кучей? Если да, то как?
2. Когда ОС передает кучу программе - она заполнена нулями?

   - Если так - почему при выводе строки, не имеющей `\0`, могут появляться лишние символы? [Здесь об этом более подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941128/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)
   - И почему в таком случае переменная, при ее создании, содержит произвольные данные из памяти?
3. Оператор `new` может запрашивать дополнительную память у ОС даже том случае, если куча имеет свободное пространство?
4. Возможно ли при такой операции `array = new char[7];` выделение более семи байт? *Округление для выравнивания?*
5. Аллокатор - механизм для выделения памяти в куче?

Comment: да, аллокатор это тот кто выделяет память. И что бы это делать он должен в той же памяти хранить ее структуру. А так как ему может быть не выгодно работать с областями менее 8 байт, он вполне может резервировать минимум 8 байт. Так же очень вероятно, что прямо после выделенного участка памяти он разместит свою информацию о состоянии следующего участка памяти. Так что очень вероятно, что после выделенных 8 байт будет не нулевая информация. Но все это только догадки. В каждой ОС все может быть по своему, включая заполнение нулями. Так же как и аллокаторы могут зависеть от ОС и компилятора

Comment: я бы сказал что тут несколько вопросов, на которые все ответы или короткие (да/нет) или впору книгу писать.

Comment: Интересно, кто может ответить на эти многочисленные вопросы,  не занимая больше мегабайта памяти в стэке

Comment: И любая переменная в C при ее создании без указанного значения содержит именно произвольные данные из памяти, где она создана. Компилятор C никогда сам не очищает память, если его об этом не просили (потому что это лишние действия, грузящие процессор и шину)

Comment: @Mike, у вас не получилось ...

Comment: Когда ядро Linux (не помню, начиная с какой версии) выделяет страницы памяти для запускаемой программы (syscall exec...) то все они инициализированы нулями.

Comment: Погодите. А при чём тут на чём написана программа? Там разве нет форматов (elf) бинарников, которые умеет выполнять процессор? Вам наверное нужно пройти курс по операционным системам и пописать на асме каком-нибудь, не ? На степике был хороший курс.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Насколько мне известно, при запуске программе выделяются две структуры памяти - стек и куча.

Ну, вообще-то при запуске программы выделяются три структуры памяти: куча, стек и статические данные. Но это уже вопрос выбранного уровня абстракции.

На уровне языка С++, например, не констатируется существования никакого "стека". Также, с точки зрения языка, не оговаривается в какой памяти живут временные объекты. Формально это может быть четвертым типом памяти.

На уровне аппаратуры регистры процессора являются отдельным типом памяти.

> В куче же некоторые ресурсы программы и другие данные: пользовательские строки, переменные - в общем, данные, появившиеся во время работы программы.

В куче традиционно находятся только безымянные объекты, созданные через средства распределения динамической памяти.

> Термин "пул" - что он означает? Он как-то связан с кучей? Если да, то как?

"Пул" - слишком расплывчатый термин. Да, обычно это отдельное хранилище, ответственное за динамическое распределение ресурсов, каким-то образом связанных между собой. Характер этой связи может быть любым. Это могут быть тесно связанные объекты одного типа, объекты одного размера и т.п. А могут быть совершенно никак внешне не похожие друг на друга ресурсы, но распределяемые одним потоком выполнения. Иногда пул организовывают лишь потому, что всю выделенную в нем память можно потом легко освободить "одним махом" вместе с самим пулом, вместо того, чтобы скурпулезно освобождать маленькие блоки по одному.

В общем, если у вас есть такая-то причина распределять память для какого-то набора объектов в некотором отдельном условно-обособленном хранилище - то вы организовываете для них пул.

> Когда ОС передает кучу программе - она заполнена нулями?

Никто не знает, когда и как ОС передает кучу программе. Это определяется реализацией. Современные ОС строятся на механизме *виртуальной памяти*. Там ничего ничем не заполнено, потому что заполнять заранее просто нечего - физически памяти изначально не существует, она "материализуется на лету" по мере обращения программы к ней. А уж чем она при этом будет заполняться - это уж как попросите.

> Если так - почему при выводе строки, не имеющей \0 могут появляться лишние символы?

Потому что, во-первых, даже память полученная от ОС не обязательно "материализуется" в заполненном нулями состоянии. Во-вторых, с чего вы вообще взяли, что эта память только что получена "от ОС"? Эта память могла уже давно находиться в распоряжении вашей программы, быть использована для тысяч разных применений и хранить оставшийся в ней мусор. ОС тут вообще ни при чем.

> Оператор new может запрашивать дополнительную память у ОС даже том случае, если куча имеет свободное пространство?

Во-первых, может. Например, если вы через `new` запросили "большой" блок памяти.

Во-вторых, почему вы вообще отделяете "кучу" от "ОС"? На некоторых платформах поддержка языковой "кучи" уже давно перекочевала из библиотеки времени выполнения в API операционной системы.

> Возможно ли при такой операции array = new char[7]; выделение более семи байт? Округление для выравнивания?

Какой именно размер имеется в виду? Тот, который доступен пользователю, или тот, который запрашивается в куче? Каждый выделенный блок памяти обычно содержит в себе еще и [служебную информацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796215/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-c-c-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/796242#796242), поэтому практически гарантированно, что будет выделено больше 7 байт. Даже вне соображений выравнивания.

> Аллокатор - механизм для выделения памяти в куче?

Что имеется в виду под словом "аллокатор"??? Английское слово? `std::allocator`? Аллокатор мелких блоков от Васи из третьего подъезда? Что-то еще?

Comment: Еще один тип памяти, это регистры

Comment: Говоря про последнее: признаться, не могу ответить. Ранее встречался с этим термином в каких-то статьях.

Comment: Который запрашивается в куче, конечно.

Comment: Выходит, если перезаписать несколько байт перед началом массива - оператор `delete` не сможет освободить память? Это ошибка среды выполнения? Программа упадет?

Comment: @Marionette: Поведение будет не определено. Произойти может что угодно. Да и какая разница?

Comment: Не более, чем любопытство

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете распределение памяти в C/C++ программе и соглашение по выделению памяти операционной системой при запуске программы.

При запуске программе, каким-то образом выделяется память, возможно, что это будет просто кусок памяти который необходимо распределить и под кучу и под стек и под статические данные.

Прослойкой между ОС и программой на конкретном языке является стартовый код, зачастую написанный на ассемблере, он то как раз запускает функцию main() в C.

Comment: Да, знаю, что PE программа начинается не с `main`, а с функции `_start`, однако эта серия вопросов не совсем об этом. Речь скорее о типах памяти, выделяемых программе для ее работы. Если совсем строго: "какие структуры памяти бывают и для чего используются?"

Comment: @Marionette, тип один - память данных, что вы вкладываете в понятие тип? Что за структуры в памяти кроме адреса?

Comment: Например, куча и стек. На низком уровне абстракции - да, это все одна и та же память для работы программы, выделенная в RAM. Но на более высоком уровне они имеют разное назначения и устройство

Comment: @Marionette, согласен но ОС не обязательно имеет к этому отношение

Comment: К чему именно? К устройству кучу и стека?